# If $f\colon\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ is differentiable and $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x) = C$ for some real number $C$. then $\lim_{x\to\infty} f'(x) = 0$?

Tags: analysis

If $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ is differentiable function and $\lim\limits_{x\to \infty} f(x) = C$ for some real number $C$.
Then $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} f^{\prime}(x) = 0$?

Comment: Use LaTeX please.

Comment: Did you have any ideas or opinions about this exercise? For example: what motivated you to ask it? Where did you find it? Have you tried anything? Do you have reason to suspect that the answer is yes/no.

Comment: As one further comment, I suggest drawing a picture of such a function where the limit of its derivative as $x \to \infty$ exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no reason why $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}f'(x)$ needs to exist.  For example, try
$$
f(x)=\frac{1}{1+x^2}\sin(x^4).
$$